# Allow NetBIOS lookup with firewalld

Tags: opensuse, firewalld

I just upgraded OpenSUSE from Leap 42.3 to Leap 15.0, and with this upgrade, OpenSUSE moved its default firewall application from **SuSEfirewall2** to **Firewalld**. I opted not to use the [`susefirewall2-to-firewalld` script](https://github.com/openSUSE/susefirewall2-to-firewalld) for migration, but to rebuild my rules from scratch. However, I cannot seem to allow NetBIOS queries to return successfully on my client machine. I have enabled both the `samba` and `samba-client` services in **Firewalld**.

For a host `hostname`, which I can ping because of DNS or access by IP address, and from which I can access my OpenSUSE machine via Samba, I try:

```
> nmblookup hostname
name_query failed to find name hostname
```

What else do I need to do to allow a NetBIOS query to succeed?

Answer (score -1):

As a result of [a discussion about this issue from the Fedora Mailing-Lists](https://lists.fedorahosted.org/archives/list/firewalld-users@lists.fedorahosted.org/message/PXOURZXHR2QVVOA2KPZVLP4HGG7ONNMF/), I added port 137 UDP to the Source Port list for the `samba-client` Service in **Firewalld** (with the `firewall-config` tool), which enabled the `nmblookup` call to succeed.

[image: firewalld configuration, with the firewall-config tool]

Comment: -1 until someone can convince me this isn't allowing any incoming UDP packet which has a source port of 137.  I guess NMBIOS stuff doesn't get connection-tracked properly because of the use of broadcast packets.